# Synthetica JProgressBar doesn't fill

Tags: java, jprogressbar, synthetica

Recently, I'm using Synthetica as default JLAF, but progress bar doesn't fill, I try the following [customize](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/customize/) sentences but, nothing changes:

`Synthetica.progressBar.x.animation.type` with a different value of `0`.
`Synthetica.progressBar.respectMinimumBarImageSize` with the recommended value of `false`.

Is there a solution?, is it a simple bug? or Is there some customize sentence that I've not seen?

I must clarify that, in other JLAF like nimbus, progress bar fills perfectly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the best way to solve the problem was deleting the sentence `Synthetica.progressBar.x.animation.type` and keeping the other as the following:

```
UIManager.put("Synthetica.progressBar.respectMinimumBarImageSize",Boolean.FALSE);
```